Installing Pyhton package from local directory error
When installing a Python package a colleague sent as a directory (with setup.py), I'm getting:
LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for '/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores'.
     
      Make sure you're either building from a fully intact git repository or PyPI tarballs. Most other sources (such as GitHub's tarballs, a git checkout without the .git folder) don't contain the necessary metadata and will not work.

Here is the full printout:
michael@michael-desktop:~/Downloads/inversion$ pip install -e s2shores
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Obtaining file:///home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:723: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'author-email' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'author_email' instead
        warnings.warn(
      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:723: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'long-description' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'long_description' instead
        warnings.warn(
      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:723: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'long-description-content-type' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'long_description_content_type' instead
        warnings.warn(
      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:723: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'project-urls' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'project_urls' instead
        warnings.warn(
      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
          setup(use_pyscaffold=True)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 459, in __init__
          _Distribution.__init__(
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 292, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 837, in finalize_options
          ep(self)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 858, in _finalize_setup_keywords
          ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
        File "/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores/.eggs/PyScaffold-3.3.1-py3.10.egg/pyscaffold/integration.py", line 140, in pyscaffold_keyword
          version_keyword(dist, keyword, setuptools_scm_config(value))
        File "/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores/.eggs/PyScaffold-3.3.1-py3.10.egg/pyscaffold/contrib/setuptools_scm/integration.py", line 17, in version_keyword
          dist.metadata.version = _get_version(config)
        File "/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores/.eggs/PyScaffold-3.3.1-py3.10.egg/pyscaffold/contrib/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 148, in _get_version
          parsed_version = _do_parse(config)
        File "/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores/.eggs/PyScaffold-3.3.1-py3.10.egg/pyscaffold/contrib/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 110, in _do_parse
          raise LookupError(
      LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for '/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores'.
     
      Make sure you're either building from a fully intact git repository or PyPI tarballs. Most other sources (such as GitHub's tarballs, a git checkout without the .git folder) don't contain the necessary metadata and will not work.
     
      For example, if you're using pip, instead of https://github.com/user/proj/archive/master.zip use git+https://github.com/user/proj.git#egg=proj
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Will appreciate any idea about what I'm missing here, thanks!

This seems to be the meaningful part: "LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for '/home/michael/Downloads/inversion/s2shores'." You need the git repository.

Thanks! The colleague who sent the package specifically instructed to use pip install -e s2shores, so I wonder what I'm (or they) are missing...

The packages uses setuptools-scm (as a build-time dependency). setuptools-scm requires the git repository information (i.e. the .git directory) to do its work. From the looks of it the .git is missing.
